# Are there macro facility for Java or C#?

Tags: c#, java, macros, inline

Macros are useful.

Therefore, I occasionally bemoan the absence of macros in Java and C#. Macros allow me to force in-line but allow me the code-manageability of non-macro code.

Is there any Java- or C#-based project/product somewhere out there that effectively allow macros or specifying in-line expansion.

I am thinking of something like

@macro public void hello(int x){ ... }

or when I call a method, an @inline annotation preceding the call would effect the called-method to be in-lined.

or, should I need to know that I should just trust the compiler to make the best the decision for me that at the best of its analysis it might in-line a call.

I hope this question will not lead to debating the pro/cons/usefulness of macros.

Comment: BTW - I found an annotation utility jatha that facilitates macros for Java written by a certain kimberly burchett http://www.kimbly.com/, (whose resume indicates she is a vp at goldman sachs). Has anyone used/evaluated it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Macros are not part of the standard Java language, and I'm not aware of any macro preprocessor being supported by mainstream Java tools, IDEs and so on.  So if you use macros in your Java code you should expect to experience some "pain".  For example,

- Source code debuggers won't let you set breakpoints relative to your original source code.
- If you share your Java-with-macros code, many Java developers are likely to turn up their noses at it, and/or complain about having to install/use extra tools.

There are quite a few examples of third-party macro pre-processors for Java; e.g. [Jatha](http://www.kimbly.com/code/jatha/), [OpenJava](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/openjava/papers/mich_2000lncs1826.pdf), [PrintMacroJ](http://www.toad.net/~jkaplan2/print/), [JavaMacros](http://code.google.com/p/java-macros/), and so on ...  (But have you ever come across a project that uses any of them?)

---

> Macros allow me to force in-line but allow me the code-manageability of non-macro code.

True.  But the JIT compiler can probably do a better job than you can in determining what *should* be inlined.  It will know (for sure) how big the chunks are, and it will have runtime stats on execution frequency, branch prediction, etc that are not available to you.

Note that there are some Hotspot JVM tuning options that can influence the optimizer's decisions on inlining; see [this page](http://jvm-options.tech.xebia.fr/), and scan for "inlin".  For instance, there is one that seems to allow you to increase the upper size threshold for an inlined method body.

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend trusting the JIT compiler to make the decision for you when it comes to inlining.

However, if you are just after macros for other purposes, in C#/.NET, there are other options.  Much of what can be done with macros for utility purposes can be done via [T4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) (Text Template Transformation Toolkit).  This is the basis for many ORM packages, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at project Lombok - http://projectlombok.org/features/Log.html

It is an annotation library that allows the following code snip-it - which (I believe) is exactly what you are speaking of.

```
 import lombok.extern.slf4j.Log;

 @Log
 public class LogExample {

   public static void main(String... args) {
     log.error("Something's wrong here");
   }
 }

 @Log(java.util.List.class)
 public class LogExampleOther {

   public static void main(String... args) {
     log.warn("Something might be wrong here");
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own annotations ... http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/annotations.html

You could also use a macro language like m4 and then invoke it with make.
http://www.gnu.org/software/m4

You could also use the C preprocessor.
The C preprocessor (cpp) is the preprocessor for the C programming language. In many C implementations, it is a separate program invoked by the compiler as the first part of translation. The preprocessor handles directives for source file inclusion (#include), macro definitions (#define), and conditional inclusion (#if). The language of preprocessor directives is agnostic to the grammar of C, so the C preprocessor can also be used independently to process other types of files

As far as suggesting tips to the compiler for optimization, Java does not have a facility to force code to be inlined.